# EKS - Node labels

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is there a way to add node labels when deploying worker nodes in EKS. I do not see an option in the CF template available for worker nodes.

[EKS-CF-Workers](https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.10.3/2018-06-05/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml/)

The only option I see right now is to use kubectl label command to add labels which is post cluster setup. However, the need to have complete automation which means applications are deployed automatically post cluster deployments and labels help in achieving the segregation.

Comment: Check this article out... Amazon EC2 Launch Templates now support the ability to expose EC2 tags in the instance metadata within K8s. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console#work-with-tags-in-IMDS

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the new EKS-optimized AMIs(amazon-eks-node-vXX) and Cloudformation template refactors provided by AWS it is now possible to add node labels as simple as providing arguments to the `BootstrapArguments` parameter of the `[amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml][1]` Cloudfomation template. For example `--kubelet-extra-args --node-labels=my-key=my-value`. For more details check the AWS announcement: [Improvements for Amazon EKS Worker Node Provisioning](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/improvements-eks-worker-node-provisioning/)

Comment: Apparently we can use commas in between to add multiple labels: --node-labels=alabel=foo,another=bar

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add the config in `user_data` and use the `--node-labels` option for the kubelet. Here's an example user_data which includes node_labels:

```
NodeLaunchConfig:
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
Properties:
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
  IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
  ImageId: !Ref NodeImageId
  InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
  KeyName: !Ref KeyName
  SecurityGroups:
  - !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      Fn::Join: [
        "",
        [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
          "CA_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY=/etc/kubernetes/pki", "\n",
          "CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH=$CA_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY/ca.crt", "\n",
          "MODEL_DIRECTORY_PATH=~/.aws/eks", "\n",
          "MODEL_FILE_PATH=$MODEL_DIRECTORY_PATH/eks-2017-11-01.normal.json", "\n",
          "mkdir -p $CA_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY", "\n",
          "mkdir -p $MODEL_DIRECTORY_PATH", "\n",
          "curl -o $MODEL_FILE_PATH https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/1.10.3/2018-06-05/eks-2017-11-01.normal.json", "\n",
          "aws configure add-model --service-model file://$MODEL_FILE_PATH --service-name eks", "\n",
          "aws eks describe-cluster --region=", { Ref: "AWS::Region" }," --name=", { Ref: ClusterName }," --query 'cluster.{certificateAuthorityData: certificateAuthority.data, endpoint: endpoint}' > /tmp/describe_cluster_result.json", "\n",
          "cat /tmp/describe_cluster_result.json | grep certificateAuthorityData | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[,\"]//g' | base64 -d >  $CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH", "\n",
          "MASTER_ENDPOINT=$(cat /tmp/describe_cluster_result.json | grep endpoint | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[,\"]//g')", "\n",
          "INTERNAL_IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)", "\n",
          "sed -i s,MASTER_ENDPOINT,$MASTER_ENDPOINT,g /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig", "\n",
          "sed -i s,CLUSTER_NAME,", { Ref: ClusterName }, ",g /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig", "\n",
          "sed -i s,REGION,", { Ref: "AWS::Region" }, ",g /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service", "\n",
          "sed -i s,MAX_PODS,", { "Fn::FindInMap": [ MaxPodsPerNode, { Ref: NodeInstanceType }, MaxPods ] }, ",g /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service", "\n",
          "sed -i s,MASTER_ENDPOINT,$MASTER_ENDPOINT,g /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service", "\n",
          "sed -i s,INTERNAL_IP,$INTERNAL_IP,g /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service", "\n",
          "DNS_CLUSTER_IP=10.100.0.10", "\n",
          "if [[ $INTERNAL_IP == 10.* ]] ; then DNS_CLUSTER_IP=172.20.0.10; fi", "\n",
          "sed -i s,DNS_CLUSTER_IP,$DNS_CLUSTER_IP,g  /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service", "\n",
          "sed -i s,CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITY_FILE,$CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH,g /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig" , "\n",
          "sed -i s,CLIENT_CA_FILE,$CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH,g  /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service" , "\n"
          "sed -i s,INTERNAL_IP/a,--node-labels tier=development,g  /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service" , "\n"
          "systemctl daemon-reload", "\n",
          "systemctl restart kubelet", "\n",
          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
          "         --stack ", { Ref: "AWS::StackName" },
          "         --resource NodeGroup ",
          "         --region ", { Ref: "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
        ]
      ]
```

The relevant line is:

```
"sed -i s,INTERNAL_IP/a,--node-labels tier=development,g  /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service" , "\n"
```

WARNING: I haven't tested this, but I do something similar and it works fine

Comment: this seems pretty ridiculous to me. What exactly does EKS help in then? Other than being a wrapper of CloudFormation?

Comment: It is ridiculous. No arguments there.

Comment: You're correct in that their Node Group offering is lacking. However, what EKS offers is a managed Control Plane. Meaning you don't have to worry about ensuring the reliability and performance of your Kubernetes master. Nor monitor the state of the (often fragile) etcd database. They also offer their own CNI which allows you to bind pods directly to ENIs on the worker nodes which then allows you to control pod access with AWS Security Groups. Honestly though the ENI binding aspect is more limiting than beneficial unless network performance is your goal. I'm considering not using EKS any longer

Comment: Also this example is a monster. and the Node Launch Config doesn't normally look this obtuse. 

Here is the official example CloudFormation file for building this:

https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-02-11/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml

Which leverages this open source AMI (Where the bootstrap.sh script lives): https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami

Comment: The original answer was pulled from the same source, it's obviously been updated since Jul 20th

Comment: Coming back to this in 2020 - I'm pretty sure this is NOT a good idea since Cloud Provider integrations are moving out-of-tree which means that the AWS Cloud Controller Manager will discover which resources it should be managing via the AWS API by Resource Labels. A requirement of the Cloud Controller Manager is that all EC2 instances have the same hostname as their AWS Private DNS Name. So updating the `--node-label` would break things.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eksctl you can add labels to the node groups:

Like so:

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: dev-cluster
  region: eu-north-1

nodeGroups:
  - name: ng-1-workers
    labels: { role: workers }
    instanceType: m5.xlarge
    desiredCapacity: 10
    privateNetworking: true
  - name: ng-2-builders
    labels: { role: builders }
    instanceType: m5.2xlarge
    desiredCapacity: 2
    privateNetworking: true
```

See https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it work with the next sed expression:

```
sed -i '/--node-ip/ a \ \ --node-labels group=node \\' /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
```

Answer (score -1):

Now with EKS managed node group, you can specify node label in CFN.

See [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-eks-nodegroup.html#cfn-eks-nodegroup-labels).